# How can I add a column to an existing pandas dataframe that consists of a static, predefined list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, addition

I have an existing dataframe and a separate list of strings. I want to add the list of strings as an additional column to the dataframe. I want the list to be the same in each row. The initial dataframe was created from an existing excel document.

I have tried using insert function withe value argument as the defined list, but I return an error - "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c'], 'b': ['d','e','f']})

testList = ['aa','bb','cc','dd']

#this is not working and returning an error
#dftest = df1.insert(2,"testList",testList)

#this is the resulting dataframe that I want
dfResult = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c'], 'b': ['d','e','f'], 'addedList': [['aa','bb','cc'],['aa','bb','cc'],['aa','bb','cc']]})

dfResult
```

I want an additional column that has the same list populated for each row as shown in the dfResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of lists the length of your dataframe and assign it to the column

```
df1['addedList']=[testList]*df1.shape[0]
df
    a   b   addedList
0   a   d   [aa, bb, cc]
1   b   e   [aa, bb, cc]
2   c   f   [aa, bb, cc]
```

Note that, if you plan on editing these lists individually after the fact, you should instead use @wenyoben's answer:

```
df1['addedList']=[['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] for x in range(len(df1))]
```

Gives the same time complexity without creating issues with pointers to the original list rather than unique list objects

Answer (score 5):

I will recommend

```
df1['addedList']=[['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] for x in range(len(df1))]
df1
Out[156]: 
   a  b     addedList
0  a  d  [aa, bb, cc]
1  b  e  [aa, bb, cc]
2  c  f  [aa, bb, cc]
```

Here is the reason why : If we create the columns by same copy , when we change the single value all others will be changed .

```
df1['addedList']=[testList]*df1.shape[0]
df1['addedList1']=[['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] for x in range(len(df1))]


df1.addedList[0][0]=11111
df1
Out[162]: 
   a  b            addedList    addedList1
0  a  d  [11111, bb, cc, dd]  [aa, bb, cc]
1  b  e  [11111, bb, cc, dd]  [aa, bb, cc]
2  c  f  [11111, bb, cc, dd]  [aa, bb, cc]
df1.addedList1[0][0]=11111
df1
Out[164]: 
   a  b            addedList       addedList1
0  a  d  [11111, bb, cc, dd]  [11111, bb, cc]
1  b  e  [11111, bb, cc, dd]     [aa, bb, cc]
2  c  f  [11111, bb, cc, dd]     [aa, bb, cc]
```